# Gelfand - Mazur theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Theorem:

Let $\mathcal {A}$ be a unital algebra over complex numbers. If every nonzero element $a$ of $\mathcal {A}$ is invertible, then $\mathcal {A}$ is isomorphic to complex numbers.
(Spoiler alert: I never took complex analysis, so my knowledge is restricted to how multiply and add complex numbers)

Proof: for any $a \in \mathcal{A}$, since the spectrum of $a$ is non-empty, there is $\lambda : \lambda 1_{\mathcal {A}} - a$ is non-invertible. Hence, as my professor concluded, $\lambda 1_{\mathcal {A}} = a$, so $\mathcal {A} = \mathbb{C} 1_{\mathcal {A}}$.

I do not follow at all. Here is the logic in my head that breaks. Please point out my mistakes at any transition.
The simplest example for $\mathcal {A}$ I can come up with is an algebra of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in complex numbers. Note that all the real-valued matrices are a subset of this algebra (which are easiest for me to think about). For a real-valued invertible matrix $A$, $A - \lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, is not equal to zero. Second, how can we even define a function if a matrix can have multiple eigenvalues? Furthermore, isomorphism is a bijection, and nonequal matrices can have (some) eigenvalues equal.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading, but it seems like this can't possibly be true. In a unital algebra, $1$ is always invertible, so this would seem to say that any unital algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, which is obviously false.

Comment: By "if any nonzero element $a$ of $\mathcal{A}$ is invertible", do you mean "all nonzero elements $a$ of $\mathcal{A}$ are invertible"?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins that is some poor wording on my part. If every non-zero element is invertible, or if all are invertible

Comment: Vakarova, eh I think it's clear enough. I just wasn't reading carefully. In any case, hopefully this clears it up if anyone has the same confusion as me.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand: I *highly* recommend that you learn complex analysis ASAP. Banach and C* theory are deeply entrenched in complex analysis.

Comment: There is complex analysis behind . The proof that the  spectrum of an element in a Banach algebra is nonempty makes use of the Liouville theorem.

Comment: @AnnaVakarova I think your example doesn't meet the theorem requirement? Not every non zero complex matrix is invertible, right?

Answer (score 2):

The proof seems fine to me. The assumption is that all non-zero elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are invertible. So,
$$a \neq 0 \implies \text{$a$ is invertible}. \tag{$\star$}$$
The contrapositive of this, which is equivalent, is
$$\text{$a$ is not invertible} \implies a = 0.$$
This is what the proof is using here. Since $\lambda$ belongs to the spectrum of $a$, by definition this means that $\lambda 1_\mathcal{A} - a$ is not invertible. By the above implication, $\lambda 1_\mathcal{A} - a = 0$, and so $a = \lambda 1_\mathcal{A}$, as concluded. Thus, for every point $a \in A$, and every point $\lambda$ in its spectrum, $a = \lambda 1_\mathcal{A}$, so the $\lambda$ in the spectrum is unique, and we can simply map $a$ to its unique point on the spectrum; that will be the isomorphism with $\mathbb{C}$.

In your example, complex $n \times n$ matrices, the assumption $(\star)$ does not hold (unless $n = 1$). It could be that only one eigenvalue is $0$, but the others are non-zero, or perhaps the matrix is non-zero and nilpotent, but either way, we get non-zero matrix that is not invertible. The proof given manages to essentially conclude that the spectrum must be unique, so multiple eigenvalues are already a giveaway.

Answer (score 2):

An algebra $A$ in which the units (= invertible elements) are all non-zero elements of $A$ is called a *division algebra*. It is not true that any unital division algebra over $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$, since, for example, one has $F=\mathbb C(t)$, the field of rational functions in a single indeterminate $t$. Indeed $F$ is certainly a field containing $\mathbb C$, and $F$ cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ because the former is not algebraically closed (*e.g.* the polynomial $x^2-t$ is irreducible in $F[x]$).

The issue with the proof is that it is not true that, given an algebra $A$ over the complex numbers, the spectrum of an element $a\in A$ must be nonempty.

This *does* hold however, the proof works fine, and, for example, for the class of unital associative *Banach algebras*, where the spectrum $\sigma(a)$ of $a \in A$ must exist since otherwise $(a-\lambda.\text{id})^{-1}$ will be an everywhere-defined (vector-valued) holomorphic function in $\lambda$ which one can show is bounded and hence constant (using a version of Liouville's theorem).

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in \mathcal{A}$ and $a \neq 0$ then $\sigma(a) = \left\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : \lambda e - a \text{ is not invertible}\right\}$ is non empty (due to another theorem). Observe also that $\sigma(a)$ only contains one point. Indeed if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \sigma(a)$ then $\lambda_1 e - a, \lambda_2 e - a \in \mathcal{A}$ and not invertible but by hypothesis every non zero element of $\mathcal{A}$ is invertible, so we must have $\lambda_1 e - a = \lambda_2 e - a = 0 $ and hence $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$.

For every $a \in  \mathcal{A}$ the equation $\lambda e = a = 0$ has solution, let's call such solution $\lambda(a)$. This map $a \to \lambda(a)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: You do not need the map $a\mapsto \lambda(a)$. The map $\lambda \mapsto \lambda.e$ gives a canonical embedding $\mathbb C \hookrightarrow A$ of the complex numbers into $A$, thus to prove the theorem you just have to show that this embedding is surjective. But if $a \in A$ and A is a Banach algebra, $\sigma(a) \neq \emptyset$ so that we may pick a $\lambda \in \sigma(a)$. Then $\lambda.e -a$ is not invertible so $\lambda.e-a=0$ and hence $a = \lambda.e$, that $A =\mathbb C.e$ as required.

Comment: I think your proof compared to mine skips the injectivity. Maybe this result I proved is stronger?

Comment: The argument I give begins with noting there is an inclusion $\mathbb C\to A$ (by the definition of a $\mathbb C$-algebra) and then proves it is an isomorphism. What injectivity statement is missing?

Comment: Nothing sorry :).